# difference between async + semphore vs sync queue

Tags: ios, multithreading

I am thinking which one is better?

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    //long operation
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(sema)
})
dispatch_semaphore_wait(sema, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
```

or sync without a_

```
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), {
    //long operation
})
```

Does the two approaches work in same way or is it an difference?

Comment: Would depend on what you want to *do* with them, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Internally, they do the same. The first is much more flexible, for example you could dispatch three tasks followed by three waits, and they can execute in parallel. The second is less code.

Comment: The second it's also clearer what you're trying to accomplish :)